# Tikz table (page break, modifying display)

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadings,arrows,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center,
                   },
                        %baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)},
        minimum height=1.0em,
        text depth=0.2em,
        text height=0.8em,
                text centered,
        nodes in empty cells,
%%
                                row 1/.style={
            nodes={
                fill=black,
                text=white,
                %font=\bfseries
            }
        },
                rows/.style={nodes={fill=gray!10}},
                columns/.style={nodes={text width = 10em}},
                %myrowstyle/.style={
                    %row #1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!10}}
        %},
    }
        }


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table, text width = 15em, text height = 2em, text depth = 2em, rows={1,...,10}{fill=gray!10}, row 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!10,
text=black}}, column 2/.append style={nodes={text width=18em}},
ampersand replacement=\&] (TabA1)
{
A1 \& A2 \\
B1 \& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Glossary}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Two questions:

1. I am using `tikz` to create a table. The first few rows are A (column A1 and A2) then I'm at the end of the page. Do I need to create another table to continue with B or is it possible to tell `tikz` to automatically break up the table?
2. I'm somewhat unsure how to deal with text depth and text height.
   Say A1 is just one word, but A2 a big text, then I would probably have to manually adjust the text height in order for the text to fit. Then I'm using text depth to make it look sort of nice. It does however feel awkard this way and in particular I want A1 to be in the middle of the row and not in the same line with the first line of text of A2.
   Is it possible that TikZ automatically does all this for me or do I need to do all of this manually?

Comment: (i) `tikzpicture` can not be broken between two pages. since your table is in float environment `table` it will in case, that is not enough place in the page, moved to the next page. (ii) in nodes definition you define `minimum width/height` so, that it will be sufficient in all cases (iii) for further help please provide complete small document, which we can copy and compile.

Comment: 1. The problem is that the table is even too big for a complete A4 page. It goes over at least 2 pages. So is there no other possibilty other than to manually break it in 2? 2. Can you maybe write the code here with what you mean "in nodes" ?

Comment: I do not want to specify minimum width/height as you propose but rather leave tikz to decide how much space it needs.

Comment: (i) your code is not possible to compile. (ii) please (again), extend your code snippet to complete small document. (iii)  your question is not clear, i suspect, that you actually looking for `longtable` not image with `tikz` matrix.

Comment: I posted a working version

Comment: let me repeat again: (i) `tikzpicture` can not be broken between pages (ii) clarify why you like to have table defined with `tikz`, isn't sufficient to have regular (long)table? it can be broken over many pages and also table cells can be well defined.  (iii) your table is in float environment `table`. it also can not be broken over more page. please extend your *mwe* with some dummy text that we can see, what you like to have. now your *mwe* works fine (let left beside unusual formatting and overwriting of cells formatting)

Comment: I added some text now...So even you said it is not possible what do u think you can still do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is extended comment ...

- it is not clear why you like to use `matrix` library from `tikz` package to design table which should be spread over two or more pages
- float environment `table` can be only on one page, if its content is larger, it will spill-out of page
- `tikzpicture` image can be only on one page. if it is bigger, it will spill-out of page
- from description can be guessed, that actually you looking for `longtable`. see, if the following example is close to what you like obtain.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% option showframe is only for test purposes
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
{
\setlength\tabcolsep{8pt}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{gray!10}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
                      |p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|
                      }
\caption{Glossary}
\label{tabA1}               \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\rowcolor{white}
\caption{Glossary (cont.)}  \\
    \hline
\endhead
\rowcolor{white}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
\lipsum[1]  &   \lipsum[2]  \\
    \hline
\lipsum[3]  &   \lipsum[4]  \\
    \hline
\lipsum[5]  &   \lipsum[6]  \\
    \end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

of course, you can stick with `tikzpicture`, however you should draw for each page separately ...